# Prove that this linear transformation is nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials, nilpotence

**The Question:**

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\Bbb C$, with linear map $T:V \rightarrow V$. Suppose that the minimal polynomial of $T$ is $$m_T(x) = p(x)q(x) \\ p(x)=(x-\lambda)^\alpha \quad q(x)=(x-\mu)^\beta \quad  \lambda \neq \mu$$

and $a$, $b$ are polynomials such that $ap+bq=1$. Define the new linear transformation

$$D = \lambda b(T)q(T)+\mu a(T)p(T)$$

Show that $T-D$ is nilpotent.

---

**My Attempt:**

In the previous parts of the question, I have shown that

(i) $V = \text{Ker}\;p(T) \oplus \text{Ker} \; q(T)$

(ii) $E:=a(T)p(T)$ and $F:=b(T)q(T)$ are projections (i.e. $E^2=E$ and $F^2=F$) with

$$\text{Im} \; E=\text{Ker} \; q(T) \qquad \quad \text{Ker} \; E = \text{Ker} \; p(T) \\ \text{Im} \; F=\text{Ker} \; p(T) \qquad \quad \text{Ker} \; F = \text{Ker} \; q(T)$$

In order to show that a linear transformation is nilpotent, we have to show that its only eigenvalue is $0$, I guess?

Now I took a vector $v \in \text{Ker} \; p(T)$ and observed that

$$v \in \text{Ker} \; p(T) \implies (T-D)(v) = Tv - \lambda v$$

Similarly,

$$v \in \text{Ker} \; q(T) \implies (T-D)(v) = Tv - \mu v$$

Moreover, since the minimal polynomial of $T$ is $(x-\lambda)^\alpha (x-\mu)^\beta$, the only eigenvalues of $T$ are $\lambda$ and $\mu$.

And then I can't quite see what the next move should be. Any hints?

Comment: A direct consequence of the Primary Decomposition Theorem is that every linear operator $T: V \rightarrow V$ is decomposed as the sum of two operators $D$ and $N$ where $D$ is diagonalizable and $N$ is nilpotent, do not I understand why you want to avoid using this theorem?

Comment: Ok, in any case, how should I go about doing this?

Comment: Hoffman and Kunze: Linear Algebra, are a good reference to propose what you need, since they work the theory of the minimal polynomial through the ideals of polynomials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing $D = \lambda F + \mu E$ and noting that $EF = FE = 0$, you can show by induction that
$$(T-D)^n = (T-\lambda)^n E + (T-\mu)^n F.$$
By (ii) this is zero when $n = \max\{\alpha,\beta\}$.